# Just re-mapped my Squarespace site to my own domain, how about my tracking snippet?

Tags: google, domains, google-analytics

I just re-routed mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com to redirect (sorry wrong word, the URLs are actually using mydomain.com) to mydomain.squarespace.com using the custom mapping for squarespace and godaddy DNS manager. My question is this, the proprietary, host analytics should still work. However, will Google Analytics still work right or do I need to tweak to get it to actually work right?

I checked that Analytics is receiving data after the transition, however, I have a few questions:

1. will it still be referring to mydomain.squarespace.com, or mydomain.com?
2. is traffic between the two the same/equivalent?
3. do I need to update my tracking script somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytics will still work. If you go to the visitors -> network properties -> hostnames section of GA you'll slowly see the mydomain.squarespace.com visits reducing and being replaced by mydomain.com. If not, there might be a problem, but this should work prefectly fine :)

Apart from this nothing should change. Numbers should stay the same (or hopefully rise if you get more popular) and you don't have to change any scripts.

Comment: thanks, i was hoping for a don't worry too much/reassurance answer. I appreciate your prompt reply :)